# Why is this statement correct?

Tags: real-analysis

"Every open subset of R is a union of closed intervals." I just don't get it. What could be an examples?

Comment: the interval $(0,1)$ is the union of $\left[ \frac 1n, 1-\frac 1n\right]$ for $n\in \mathbb N$ , for example.

Comment: *Every* nonempty subset $S$, not just open, is a union of closed intervals, namely $[a, a]$ for each $a \in S$.

Comment: (I previously wrote that this was false for $\emptyset$ depending on your definition of "interval"; for clarity, that's just nonsense. $\emptyset$ is the union of no closed intervals, whatever the definition of "interval".)

Comment: @PatrickStevens  Nitpick $\emptyset = \cup_{x\in \emptyset} [x, x+1]$.  The emptyset is an *empty* union of closed intervals.

Comment: I'd say the definition of closed interval $[a,b]$ requires $a< b$.  We can prove this statement by noting if $S$ is (non-empty) open and $p\in S$ then there is an open interval $(p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon)$ around $p$.  $(p-\epsilon, p+\epsilon) = \cup_{0< \sigma < \epsilon} [p-\sigma, p+\sigma]$ and we can do that for all $p\in S$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "the union of no closed intervals".